# Python: Serial Transmission

Tags: python, serial-port

I have an image stack of 500 images (jpeg) of 640x480. I intend to make 500 pixels (1st pixels of all images) as a list and then send that via COM1 to FPGA where I do my further processing.

I have a couple of questions here:

1. How do I import all the 500 images at a time into python and how do i store it?
2. How do I send the 500 pixel list via COM1 to FPGA?

I tried the following:

1. Converted the jpeg image to intensity values (each pixel is denoted by a number between 0 and 255) in MATLAB, saved the intensity values in a text file, read that file using `readlines()`. But it became too cumbersome to make the intensity value files for all the 500 images!
2. Used NumPy to put the read files in a matrix and then pick the first pixel of all images. But when I send it, its coming like: `[56, 61, 78, ... ,71, 91]`.

Is there a way to eliminate the `[ ]` and `,` while sending the data serially?

Thanks in Advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ad 1: Use a library like [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) for accessing the images. You can load an image using

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("img000.jpg")
```

And access the first pixel value using

```
pixel = im.getpixel(0,0)
```

This returns a color tuple for the first pixel, you have to calculate the intensity from this.

Ad 2: This depends on how your FPGS expects the values? Since you mentioned *eliminating `[`* , do you need a comma-separated ASCII string? Try

```
pixel_string = ','.join([str(x) for x in pixel_list])
```

If you need to send a series of bytes construct the byte string like

```
pixel_string = ''.join([chr(x) for x in pixel_list])
```

Both examples assume, that you have constructed you list of intensity values in `pixel_list`.

Comment: Thank you Martin. That was very helpful.
Can you tell me a way to import more than one image at a time. Like, sort of GUI in which I can select more than one image by pressing "Ctrl" and then clicking OK will select all the images and import them into a matrix in python.

Lets say, I want to import 10 grey scale images.. I open the GUI, select 10 images and then after clicking okay, I should be able to get a matrix of dimensions row*col*10. 

Can you please help me how to do it? I couldnt figure out myself..

Thank you in advance :)

s-elektron

Comment: and one more small correction..

it should be:
pixel = im.getpixel((0,0)) i suppose.. im.getpixel(0,0) was not working in Python 2.6. I haven't tried in other versions though